# Pandas Read Excel function convert index to list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

```
## Summary: Analyze the data in each sheet and get the result
def analyze_data(project, sheet):
    print(project_dict[project],'****'+sheet)

    ## Get data with specific finding type in validation sheet
    sheet_df = pd.read_excel(project_dict[project],sheet, na_values=['NA'])
    print(sheet_df['Feedback Report']=='S.No')
    # Get index of tables
    242 idx = sheet_df[sheet_df['Feedback Report']=='S.No'].index.tolist()[0]
    243 head = idx - 1

    245 header_df = sheet_df.iloc[0:head,:]
    246 sheet_df = sheet_df.iloc[idx:,:]


    ## Replace the header
    header = sheet_df.iloc[0]
    sheet_df.columns = header.tolist()
    sheet_df = sheet_df[1:]

    ####################################
    ## Get data from the time period
```

The above code is not written by me and I am supposed to make a complete windows executable for it. I am not able to understand what the code is trying to do in line 242.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File 37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File QA_Review_Reporting.py", line 751, in sync
        report.read(project_dict)
      File reports.py", line 705, in read
        process()
      File reports.py", line 749, in process
        get_valid_type(project)
      File reports.py", line 185, in get_valid_type
        counts = analyze_data(project, item)
      File reports.py", line 242, in analyze_data
        idx = sheet_df[sheet_df['Feedback Report']=='S.No'].index.tolist()[0]
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Line 242 is filtering the dataframe `sheet_df` to rows where the `'Feedback Report'` column has a value of `'S.No'`. Then it is returning the corresponding `index` of the filtered dataframe to a list and taking the first element in that list via `[0]`.

Comment: @rahlf23 Thanks for prompt response. What is the index for precisely? Is it the0-indexed row number?

Comment: Correct, assuming this is a single indexed dataframe (not a `MultiIndex`). So if after filtering, your dataframe only contains rows (`1`, `3` and `7`), those would be your indices that are returned in the list. Taking the first element of that list would return `1` in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, Line 242 is filtering the dataframe `sheet_df` to rows where the `'Feedback Report'` column has a value of `'S.No'`. Then it is returning the corresponding index of the filtered `sheet_df` dataframe to a list and taking the first element in that list via `[0]`.

For example:

```
sheet_df = pd.DataFrame([['No', 1, 2, 3], ['S.No', 4, 5, 6], ['S.No', 7, 8, 9], ['Yes', 10, 11, 12]], columns=['Feedback Report', 'Val 1', 'Val 2', 'Val 3'])
```

Which yields:

```
  Feedback Report  Val 1  Val 2  Val 3
0              No      1      2      3
1            S.No      4      5      6
2            S.No      7      8      9
3             Yes     10     11     12
```

Filtering the dataframe via `sheet_df[sheet_df['Feedback Report']=='S.No']` will return:

```
  Feedback Report  Val 1  Val 2  Val 3
1            S.No      4      5      6
2            S.No      7      8      9
```

Then taking the index and sending `tolist()`:

```
[1, 2]
```

Finally, take the first element via `[0]` to return:

`1`

Comment: Great! Thanks! This error is occurs in most of the files that DO have S.No. because the index is empty :( Still not sure why. Will have to check the excel files.

Comment: Try `reset_index()` if that is truly the case.

Comment: Didn't work. It is a ````MultiIndex````. I am on it. Thanks again.

Comment: Here are my excel files. One is working other is not. I think an empty file with a bare template might be giving this error. https://imgur.com/a/GRcv2Kq

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you intend to read those files in... I would create a minimal example and post your exact error as another question.